# How to get attribute content Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I have

```
 <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2015-01-26 12:37:00">
```

and I want to select the **content**. I try without success:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.somesite.com/index.html").get();
Element link= doc.select("meta").first(); 
String contetn= link.attr("content");
```

But in my html I have:

```
<div style="overflow: visible;" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.somesite.com/index.html">
<meta itemprop="headline" content="some text">
<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2015-01-26 12:37:00">
<meta itemprop="dateModified" content="2015-01-26 14:03:16">
```

You can see that I search for the 3-td tag meta and I can't select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Element link= doc.select("meta").first();
```

This will select only the first `meta`-element found; since you have more than one in your second html, you'll get the wrong result.

But here's an **example**:

```
final String html = "<div style=\"overflow: visible;\" itemscope=\"\" itemtype=\"http://schema.org/Article\">\n"
        + "<meta itemprop=\"url\" content=\"http://www.somesite.com/index.html\">\n"
        + "<meta itemprop=\"headline\" content=\"some text\">\n"
        + "<meta itemprop=\"datePublished\" content=\"2015-01-26 12:37:00\">\n"
        + "<meta itemprop=\"dateModified\" content=\"2015-01-26 14:03:16\">";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Element meta = doc.select("meta[itemprop=datePublished]").first();
String content = meta.attr("content");

System.out.println(content);
```

**Output:** `2015-01-26 12:37:00`

This will select all `meta`-elements with attribute `itemprop` and attribute value `datePublished`. From all found, just the first is taken. Finally from the single element you can get the value of the `content`-attribute.

Comment: oo thanks, I searched for method second(), third() but I did not find such. That solution is very elegant. Thanks again.

Comment: With `elements.get(index)` - where `index` is the position (int) - you'll get all other positions. In fact `first()` is not much more than `elements.get(0)` with an additional check for empty content. So eg. `second()` is just `get(1)`.

Comment: Yes, but if the Html changes in the future, or if the meta tags will be rearranged, index search will not work. So the first solution is better for me.